# Integration in a semicircle

Tags: complex-analysis

> Evaluate : $$\int_\Gamma(z^2+3\bar z)\,dz$$ where $\Gamma$ is the upper half of the unit circle from $-1$ to $+1$.

First put , $z=e^{i\theta}, 0\le\theta\le\pi$ and take a negative sign as the direction is clockwise. Finally I got $\frac{2}{3}-3\pi i$.

Am I in right direction ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Taking note of the negative sign is important.

Answer (score 1):

Another parametrization for $\Gamma$ would be
$$
\gamma(t)=e^{i(\pi-t)}\quad 0\le t\le \pi.
$$
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_\Gamma(z^2+3\bar{z})\,dz&=&\int_0^\pi -i(e^{2i(\pi-t)}+3e^{-i(\pi-t)})e^{i(\pi-t)}\,dt=-i\int_0^\pi[e^{-i3(t-\pi)}+3]\,dt\\
&=&-i\left[\frac{-1}{3i}e^{-i3(t-\pi)}+3t\right]_0^\pi=\frac23-3\pi i.
\end{eqnarray}